# How persist some state between routes with vue & vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

I have a navigation flow consisting in

```
SearchPage -> ...Others or SearchPage -> ...Others or SearchPage ->
```

and wanna persist what was the search string when navigate back.

```
<template id="ListCustomersPage">
<q-layout>
  <q-layout-header>
    <toolbar :title="title" :action="doCreate" label="New"></toolbar>
    <q-search inverted placeholder="Type Name, Code, Nit, Phone Number or Email" float-label="Search" v-model="search" />
    <q-btn icon="search" color="secondary" @click="doSearch" />
  </q-layout-header>
</q-layout>
</template>
```

Now, the problem is how correlate the stack of the queries and the one of the routers, when the fact the user can navigate elsewhere.

P.D All is in a single page. If possible to persist the screen without refresh them (but only for the search pages until popped back) will be better.

Answer (score 5):

## Option 1: Navigation Guards

You can use a so called [Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) that allows you to add global actions before, after and on route updates. You can also add it directly to your component by using the [In-component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards), which will allow you to persist the content of the `search` data.

```
const VueFoo = {
   // I guess your search attribute is in your data
    data() {
      return {
        search: ''
      }
  },
  mounted() {
      // retrieve your information from your persistance layer
  },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    // called when the route that renders this component is about to
    // be navigated away from.
    // has access to `this` component instance.

     // persist this.search in localstorage or wherever you like it to be stored
  }
}
```

## Option 2: Using a (Vuex) Store

If you're able to add a `Vuex Store` or any Store alike, I would highly recommend to do so. Since you tagged quasar I want to link to the [Vuex Store Documentation](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-vuex-store.html) provided there. You can basically outsource your `search` property and let the Store persist it for you across your application.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    search_term: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_SEARCH_TERM (state, payload) {
      state.search_term = payload.search_term
    }
  },
  actions: {
    SEARCH ({ commit, state }, payload) {
      commit('SET_SEARCH_TERM', payload.search_term)

      // your api call to search which can also be stored in the state
    }
  }
})
export default store
```

In your component where you want to persist your search query using a mutation (not bound to an action):

```
store.commit('SET_SEARCH_TERM', {
  search_term: this.search // your local search query
})
```

In your code where you trigger the search ACTION if you want to persist during every search

```
store.dispatch('SEARCH', {
  search_term: this.search
})
```

Accessing the property `search_term` or however you want to call it can be done using a computed property. You can also bind the state and mutations directly without the need for Navigation guards at all:

```
// your Vue component
computed: {
  search: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.search_term
    },
    set (val) {
      this.$store.commit('SET_SEARCH_TERM', { search_term: val })
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to learn about the basic concept before using: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: I have a store but the problem is that when the user finish the workflow the search must reset for the next. So how know when the cycle start or clear search?

Comment: Why not let the user decide? You could go for either a checkbox that would allow them to persist and introduce a clear search term button or you could persist by default and only add that button - if you can’t determine if it is the start of a new search those are the options I can think of without knowing your project.

Comment: For this case the search must clear every time. Is for creating invoices/orders. My main problem is how detect when I start the workflow and clear the rest of the search in the stack.

Comment: There is actually a third option. Store it in a simple javascript module, that is imported from your component. These are initialized only once on the first load.