# How to Suppress Fetch Occurring in Parent View (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a View.js application that includes two views - Articles.vue and Article.vue - such that Article.vue is nested within Articles.  Here is how these views behave:

1. When the Articles created() lifecycle event fires, this view fetches a list of accounts via HTTP and renders links to Article.vue within a v-for loop.
2. A user can then click on an Article in the Articles view.  This links to the child Articles.vue, which then shows details of the Article.

The issue that I am having is that when step 2 occurs, the Articles view recreates (i.e. the created() event re-fires, and the Articles list is unnecessarily re-retrieved.)  This causes an unwanted delay and screen flash that makes the app feel less responsive.

What I would like is for the Articles view to render only once, and not each time an Article is clicked on.  How might I accomplish this?

I do get the desired behavior if I include the Articles component directly in the home page, instead of linking to it as a view from the home page.  However, since the Articles view is only intended to appear when the user selects this functionality, this direct inclusion is not a viable approach.

Also, I have come upon keep-alive, which I see will prevent the parent route from re-rendering.  However, keep-alive is be too broad, as I do want the parent view to reload if the parent vue link is clicked again (i.e. to retrieve new Articles); I just don't want the view to reload if the child vue link is clicked.

Possibly, the answer lies in Navigation Guards:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

However, I am new to Vue and am not able to parse documentation on this feature to arrive at my solution.

Following is the relevant code:

***Articles***

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <br />
    <div v-for="Article in Articles" :key="Article.ArticleID">
        <router-link :to="{name: 'Article', params: {'ArticleID': Article.ArticleID}}">{{Article.ArticleName}}</router-link>
    </div>
    <br />
    <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "Articles",
        data() {
            return {
                Articles: []
                }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getArticles();
        },
        methods: {
            getArticles: function() {
                console.log("Getting data");
                const url = "http://localhost:8001/articles"

                fetch(url)
                .then( (response) => {
                    console.log("Converting data to json");
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then( (data) => {
                    if (typeof(data[0].ArticleID)=="undefined") {
                        console.log("No data found.");
                    } else
                    {
                        console.log("Data found");
                        this.Articles = data;
                    }
                })
                .catch( err => console.log("Error retrieving data: " + err));
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

***Routes Section***

```
  {
    path: "/articles",
    name: "Articles",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "y" */ "../views/Articles.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/article/:ArticleID",
        name: "Article",
        props: true,
        component: () => 
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "z" */ "../components/Article.vue")
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This is a good case for Vuex global state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487836/how-persist-some-state-between-routes-with-vue-vue-router